# Required Field Msg for empty Textbox

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the below Codeigniter Code i place the view Part .When i click submit button without entering data in the textbox it should display Required Field Which i left empty.Pls help me to do.

```
<?php

echo form_open('contact/create_member');

echo form_input('name', set_value('name', ' Name'));
echo form_input('email_address', set_value('email_address', 'Email Address'));
echo form_input('college_name', set_value('college_name', 'college_name'));
echo form_input('address', set_value('address', 'address'));
echo form_input('phone_number', set_value('phone_number', 'phone_number'));
echo form_textarea('message', set_value('message', 'message'));
echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Initially you will refer the Codeigniter Form validations

[link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)
you can under stand every thing about Server side validation's .

Important Note:

please know the what type of validation do you want means (Clint side or Server Side).

Then only you proceed man.

clintside validation jquery plugin and example find here:

http://jqueryvalidation.org/